# Many to Many query Azure Tables

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services, azure-blob-storage

I have been using Azure where every users item is their own, however I want to expand my app, how can I allow multiple users access to the same row in my table?

At the moment I have **userId** and **projectId.** I then query for **userId** and all of the users projects are returned.

```
 prodjectid   userid
    1           1
    2           1 
    3           2  
    4           3     
    5           3
```

I now essentially want a row to have a **projectId** but multiple **userIds** and then query against all the **userIds** of each row. As Below

```
 prodjectid   userid
    1           1
    2           1,2 
    3           2  
    4           3     
    5           3,1
```

I am not sure however if this the best way to go about it. I am new to database development and so need some guidance. What would be the best thing for me to do?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using SQL Azure or Azure Storage Table? They are completely different.

Comment: Hello I am using Azure Mobile Service which links to an Azure Storage Table

Answer (score 0):

I think you should design your table in this way

## tablename : project

```
id prodjectid userid
1   1           1
2   2           1
```

that means a user may be involve in more than 1 project. now to get the all projectid of a particular user just run the query as follow

```
select *from project  where userid='1'
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply but it doesn't quite do what I need, I have added and example to my question to explain.